# Sorting deque of boost tuples

Tags: c++, sorting, boost, stl, boost-tuples

Not sure if I have a simple typo somewhere, but I'm running into issues in sorting a deque of tuples.

So, my deque looks like this:

```
std::deque<boost::tuple<unsigned int, unsigned int> > messages;
```

And then I have my call to sort:

```
sort(messages.begin(), messages.end(), msg_sort_criteria);
```

And my sorting function:

```
bool msg_sort_criteria(boost::tuple<unsigned int, unsigned int> lhs, boost::tuple<unsigned int, unsigned int> rhs)
{
  return boost::get<1>(lhs) < boost::get<1>(rhs);
}
```

What happens is that I get errors in stl_heap.h and stl_algo.h.
For instance,

> Called object type '`<bound member function type>`' is not a function or
>   function parameter.

---

Edit:

For clarification, this is all taking place within private members of a class.

```
class Messages::MessageImpl{
private:
  std::deque<boost::tuple<unsigned int, unsigned int> > messages;

  bool msg_sort_criteria(boost::tuple<unsigned int, unsigned int> lhs, boost::tuple<unsigned int, unsigned int> rhs)
  {
    return boost::get<1>(lhs) < boost::get<1>(rhs);
  }

  void fn()
  {
    sort(msg_queue_.begin(), msg_queue_.end(), msg_sort_criteria);
  }
}
```

Comment: Is `msg_sort_criteria` a free function or a member function? If the former, you need to show more code; if the latter, make it `static` and change `sort(messages.begin(), messages.end(), msg_sort_criteria);` to `sort(messages.begin(), messages.end(), &myClassName::msg_sort_criteria);`.

Comment: All of this code is taking place within private members of a class.  I'll update accordingly

Comment: Are you intentionally only sorting by the first member of the `tuple`? If you don't care about the order of items where the first element is equal you can just use the default tuple `operator<` and don't bother with a sort predicate at all.

Comment: The first element is going to be unique (it is an ID) and the second element is a timestep, which I'm attempting to sort by.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<sup>Mostly reposting from comment.</sup>

Change your implementation to:

```
class Messages::MessageImpl{
private:
  std::deque<boost::tuple<unsigned int, unsigned int> > messages;

  static bool msg_sort_criteria(boost::tuple<unsigned int, unsigned int> lhs,
                                boost::tuple<unsigned int, unsigned int> rhs)
  {
    return boost::get<1>(lhs) < boost::get<1>(rhs);
  }

  void fn()
  {
    sort(msg_queue_.begin(), msg_queue_.end(), &MessageImpl::msg_sort_criteria);
  }
};
```